# SIGINT (ctrl-c) not instant for ping

Tags: linux, ping

At times I run a `ping` command (on GNU/Linux) and it won't stop immediately when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

To my understanding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> sends a SIGINT. What are possible causes of the `ping` command to not exit immediately?

What can I do to make sure it always exits instantly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programs can bind custom handlers to the SIGINT signal, for example to perform cleanup actions. You can observe this behaviour with this shell script, which binds a handler using trap:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap "echo Caught!" SIGINT SIGTERM

while true
do sleep 60
done
```

To kill an interactive program instantly, you can either do `kill -9 <PID>` in another shell, or use ctrl-Z to suspend the program and then kill it:

```
❯ /tmp/test.sh    # Our test script with trap
^CCaught!         # Ctrl-c doesn't work
^Z                # Suspend the process
[1]  + 11713 suspended  /tmp/test.sh
❯ kill -9 %1
[1]  + 11713 killed
```

Here I'm using %1 to get the pid of this first background process, which is the script because I have no other background processes in this example. You can also use the PID of the process directly, for shells that don't support the %1 syntax.

---

And that's what ping does, just look at the [source code](http://sourceforge.net/p/iputils/code/ci/HEAD/tree/): In the main function, [setup](http://sourceforge.net/p/iputils/code/ci/HEAD/tree/ping.c#l588) is called, which [sets signal handlers](http://sourceforge.net/p/iputils/code/ci/HEAD/tree/ping_common.c#l682), including SIGINT. SIGINT is bound to [sigexit](http://sourceforge.net/p/iputils/code/ci/HEAD/tree/ping_common.c#l392), which sets a flag to notify the mainloop that ping should exit. This flag is only checked in [two](http://sourceforge.net/p/iputils/code/ci/HEAD/tree/ping_common.c#l726) [places](http://sourceforge.net/p/iputils/code/ci/HEAD/tree/ping_common.c#l468). I guess  that one of the system calls used there blocks or takes some time to return, so the flag will never be checked or only after a delay.

Comment: You're suggesting that ping binds custom handlers to the SIGINT signal. Still I'd love to know what I can investigate to track down the cause of this behaviour.

Comment: @silviot I've linked some lines of the ping source code, where the SIGINT handler is bound.